# Split string and convert to integer in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I have string like this - > `"46999 - Lamp"`

My purpose is that , if this string contains `"-"` I want to split to string and get number`(46999)` and assign to my integer value. In .net how can we do this ?

Best regards

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Search for Split() and string to int conversion. You will get lot of results on google

Comment: `int result = int.Parse(source.Split('-')[0]);`

Comment: There´s a `Split`-method defined on `string` and a `Convert.ToInt32` or even `int.Parse`. What else do you need?

Comment: Use split using dash and space which will trim extra spaces :             string input = "46917 - Shampoo";
            string[] split = input.Split(new char[] { ' ', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: With `c#7+` - `int.TryParse(yourString.Split('-')[0], out int result);`.

Comment: Also you can do: `Regex regex = new Regex("\\d{1,}"); string numString = regex.Match(str).Value;` then parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 string myStr= "46917 - Shampoo";

 if (myStr.Contains('-')) {
    string[] tokens = myStr.Split('-');
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(tokens[0].Trim());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this

and then use `i` anywhere u want

```
string data = "46917-Shampoo";
int i;
if (data.Contains("-")) 
{
    string[] mydata = data.split('-');
    i = Convert.ToInt32(mydata[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 string textValue = "46917 - Shampoo";
 string[] spArray = textValue.Split('-');
 int final = int.Parse(spArray[0].Trim());
```

Comment: There is `IndexOf(char)` overload for that.

Comment: @Sharon: What happens if `textValue` contains garbage? The OP also asked to check whether `-` was present, in which case only the integer should be assigned. I think the code you currently show should be updated to cater for these.

Comment: agreed @Laurent LA RIZZA. We can use int.TryParse instead, so that it will capture  any exceptions.             bool isValid = int.TryParse(index[0].Trim(), out final);

Answer (score 0):

For only the conversion from string to integer, use `int.Parse()` or `int.tryParse()`.